# Adding trusted sites to all users in a machine

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-registry

I am trying to add trusted sites for all users in a computer. To go about this I would have to add it in the Local Machine part of the registry.

However, any changes I make to the ZoneMap associated with HKLM is NOT being reflected in the browser settings. I know GPOs are a way to overcome this but I am trying to get this done without touching GPOs.

What I have tried so far:

1. Searching the internet with my current knowledge, finding people with similar problems and no solutions yet.
2. Logging in as local admin and making changes to both registry directly and changing IE trusted sites settings.
3. Logging in as Domain admin and doing the above. In both cases only the Current User part of the registry got affected when I changed using IE's trusted sites and local machine registry changes were completely ignored.

I am using Windows 8 and IE 11.

Comment: Consider posting the actual registry keys you touched and changes you made. Also, why go out of your way not to use Group Policy?

Comment: Hey, I am considering a non GPO approach currently. We are really digging around for a way to do it. Ofcourse plan B is GPO.  

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\hello.com  
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\hello.com\www  
https: REG_DWORD 0x00000002  

The above is the change I made to HKLM which isn't getting reflected.